# Merging two PNG images with the smaller image behind with GD

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick, gd

I am attempting to merge two png images by placing a smaller png behind an image with a "hole" in the center with transparency.

The "Front" image is **$src** in this example
The "Back" image is **$dest** in the example

[image: Example 1]

So far, i've gotten it to work in reverse (by putting the $dest image / smaller image in front) using the following code:

```
imagecopymerge($src, $dest,  300, 150, 0, 0, 150, 150, 100);
```

However, i'm not sure how to do it with the smaller image "Behind" the bigger image so that it fits perfectly in the hole.

Do I need to recreate the image ($dest) as a larger image (500 x 500) to "paste" the $src image over top of with 0 offset? This stuff is confusing :S

Comment: I don't think you can merge a larger source onto a smaller destination. You should crop the dest to be exactly 150x150 or whatever size your window is and copy it on top of the larger image.
Or you could do it the way you're suggesting.

Comment: @mkaatman You are correct, I solved it. Just typing out the question above helped me solve it :) Putting the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

First I merged the smaller image onto a blank image below that matched the larger image.

Then, I merged the image with the hole onto the new image created above. See as follows:

```
// Get size of larger image
$sz = getimagesize("larger.jpg");

// Create resources
$backing = imagecreatetruecolor($sz[0],$sz[1]);
$img1 = imagecreatefrompng("larger.jpg");
$img2 = imagecreatefrompng("smaller.jpg");

// Merge backing
imagecopymerge($backing, $img2,  300, 150, 0, 0, 150, 150, 100);

// Merge main
imagecopymerge($backing,$img1,  0, 0, 0, 0, $sz[0], $sz[1], 100);

// Save new image
imagepng($backing,$save);

// Destroy resources
imagedestroy($backing);
imagedestroy($img1);
imagedestroy($img2);
```

Hope this helps someone!